# Can i use RabbitMQ to move data to Amazon Kinesis stream?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amazon-kinesis

I have a server containing folders date wise and each folder further contains many files (size 200kb each) containing all the log for a particular day. I am new to RabbitMQ , while going through the documentation of RabbitMQ i found below code for Producer

Refer Link: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/java/Send.java

```
public class Send {

  private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
    String message = "Hello World!";
    channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
    System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");

    channel.close();
    connection.close();
  }
}
```

on the above code i have added sample string  "Hello World!" to publish. As stated above in the problem description that i have to read the log information from the server with different date stamp directory So do i need to write a simply an infinite loop(as logs are continuously updated) and recursively read all directory and files and Then for each line of File i can compose a message and then publish it to receiver ?

In this case our channel will never close and Connection will be always up is it an idle condition with RabbitMQ ?

Is it possible for RabbitMQ to mark the file which are read and don't read it again OR i need to manage it programmatically like renaming the file and folder with some different names. I was thinking this as might be our program gets terminated with some power failure or something while i am in mid of any file and then how can i guarantee that records would not be duplicated ?

Any other best way to achieve this would be great help for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would enqueue a list of files to process to RabbitMQ and then have a separate set of processes picking up messages from that queue to do what you want with the data. Then try to make sure to subscribe to the queues in ack mode, so RabbitMQ will only delete the message from the queue once you ack it. With this setting, you should prevent sending the same information twice.

That would work on *most* situations. I say most, because if RabbitMQ sends a message to your consumer, then your consumer takes an action (like replicating the information, or placing an entry on a database) and then the connection to RabbitMQ dies *before* you sent the ack to RabbitMQ, then the broker has no way of telling that you already processed the message, so it will deliver it again later.

Comment: Thanks... To "enqueue a list of files" to be processed i was looking some ready made solutions here as i have parent folder and that will contain many folders containing files. As this the files would be keep on generating so i was looking some kind of solution where i can configure the root folder name and if any changes happens in the  nested folder item somehow it senses and keep sending those information to RabbitMQ ?

Comment: I think you would have to implement that logic for listening on file system changes yourself.

Comment: Seems i got something better with java 7 feature. Now they are providing a WatchService on a file\directory and we can receive events for file create\modify\delete. This is making my work simple and more robust for listening file system. Thanks